# What are these features on the V-22 ospreys rotor?

Tags: tiltrotor, v-22, rotor-head

On the outside of the V-22s rotor fairings there seems to be some kind of hinged weights directly opposite of each of the three rotor blades. Does anybody know what their purpose is?[image]

Comment: They appear to move from side to side in that curved slot, either passively or by actuation, so they are likely used to control vibration/harmonics in some way by offsetting the center of mass of the hub. That kind of thing looks like a bandaid, developed to fix a problem to avoid a bigger redesign.

Comment: And also with that aerodynamic shape I expect that they rotate to align with the local airflow.

Comment: If I were to take an educated guess I might say they are counterweights to provide a countervailing force that drives the blades to a safe pitch angle in case of actuator failure.